# Запретить выход из приложения (Kiosk Mode)

Tags: java, android, c#, xamarin

Необходимо запустить приложение для андройда в режиме "Kiosk Mode". Необходимо, чтобы пользователь не мог закрыть или свернуть приложение, а также войти в настройки устройства.

Стоит задача сделать приложение для отзывов. Работать оно будет на планшете, доступном клиентам.

Для достижения поставленной задачи я уже сделал следующее (используется Xamarin):

- Запустил приложение как лаунчер и развернул приложение на весь экран:

  ```
  [Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon",
      Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen")]
  [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionMain }, Categories = new[] { 
      Intent.CategoryHome, Intent.CategoryDefault })]
  ```
- Сделал пустым обработчик события кнопки назад:

  ```
  public override void OnBackPressed(){}
  ```

Сейчас пользователь может использовать панель уведомлений и кнопку домой и кнопку назад. Доступ к кнопкам домой и назад не страшен, так как кнопка домой возвращает пользователя к приложению, и из меню задач лаунчер (это приложение) закрыть нельзя.

Необходимо заблокировать панель уведомлений или сделать так, чтобы ее использовать было практически невозможно (чтобы пользователь не смог зайти в настройки, выключить Wi-fi и так далее). **Есть рут права**.

**Использовать изоленту, бесцветный лак, ломать тачскрин и другие аппаратные способы блокирования доступа к панели уведомлений использовать нельзя.**

**Дополнение 1**

Использование следующего кода приводит к полному отключению экрана до перезагрузки. Возможно, если команда для отключения только строки состояния?

```
Java.Lang.Process proc = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(
    new String[] { "su", "-c", "service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui" });
proc.Wait();
```

**Дополнение 2**

При использовании программ [full!screen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.tsorn.FullScreen&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImRlLnRzb3JuLkZ1bGxTY3JlZW4iXQ) и [Hide System Bar(Full Screen)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dreamori.hidebar) программа не отображается. Отображается только картинка рабочего стола и больше ничего до перезагрузки. Планшет Prestigo multipad weze 3341 3g (PMT 3341_3G), android 5.1.1

Comment: На сколько я знаю в гугле предусмотрели ваши порывы и запретили чего то там запрещать, типа "чтобы клиент не смог свернуть или закрыть приложение"

Comment: Может если есть рут права можно все таки как-то убрать строку состояния? или отключить определенную область сенсора чтобы пользователь просто не мог нажать на место, где можно вызвать строку состояния.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убил строку состояния приложением Custom Quick Settings и командами под рутом:

```
settings put secure user_setup_complete 0
settings put global device_provisioned 0
```

Answer (score 5):

Похоже, что вам нужeн `Single-Purpose Devices`. Официальная документация [Set up Single-Purpose Devices](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html)

Ещё есть статья на русском с разными хаками по ограничениям взаимодействия пользователя с устройством [Kiosk Mode приложения на Android](https://habrahabr.ru/post/149561/)

На Xamarin можно использовать любые нативные API, насколько мне известно. Так что думаю с этим проблем возникнуть не должно.

Answer (score 3):

Kiosk mode - это не фул-скрин, а полная блокировка bottom и status bar. Тогда пользователь действительно не сможет ничего сделать, помимо использования функционала программы (если конечно программа не выбросит ошибку).

Мне приходилось делать такую программу, но использовалось средствами Android Studio, а не Xamarin. Делать это можно как через функцию:

```
private void hideBar(){
try
{
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui"}); 
    proc.waitFor();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("ROOT ERROR", ex.getMessage());
}
```

}

Или через `shell`:

```
adb shell
su 
pm disable com.android.systemui //(enable) чтобы включить обратно
```

Возможно следующие команды помогут добиться желаемого результата и с помощью Xamarin.

Из личного опыта советую создать плавающие системные кнопки управления (как минимум "назад") которая появляется при выходе из приложения. На случай, когда приложение вылетает или надо что-то поменять в настройках Вам не придется включать `.systemui` обратно.

Comment: Я пробовал сделать как вы предложили. После использования функции экран гаснет и не включается до перезагрузки устройства. Возможно, конечно, что виноват xamarin. Может есть команда для того, чтобы просто отключить строку состояния? Я имею в виде вместо отключения всего интерфейса устройства. На xamarin функция выглядит так:                     Java.Lang.Process proc = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui" });
                    proc.Wait();

Comment: @mirypoko через консоль не пробовали? Если Вам не нужно убирать/добавлять `.systemui` динамически, то такой вариант Вам должен подойти. Так как Вы напрямую обращаетесь к устройству как суперюзер Вам не придется ничего подтверждать на самом устройстве. Экран выключаться не должен. Будет анимация скрытия нижнего и верхнего бара.

Comment: После ввода команд с консоли строка состояния не исчезла https://pp.userapi.com/c639530/v639530140/2625d/ZBGBEJuh94o.jpg . Может я сделал что-то не так? Может команды нужно ввести в другую консоль?

Comment: @mirypoko а Вы когда делали через функцию, то у вас был запрос прав суперюзера для выполнения? Если нет, то могут быть проблемы с самим рут доступом. Это же указывает и на то, что когда Вы обратились к устройству через консоль и прописали заблокировать `.systemui` ничего не произошло.
Я на самом деле никогда не работал с `Xamarin`, но это первое логичное предположение, которое пришло в голову.

Comment: Всегда запрашивало права суперпользователя. Как при использовании функции, так и после введения команды su. При блокировке .systemui единственное что поменялось, это обои на рабочем столе пропали. При активации возвращаются назад.

Comment: @mirypoko тогда я бы еще попробовал скачать Android Studio, подключить устройство, запустить даже дефолтное приложение и попробовать прописать в консоле тоже самое. Если это поможет, значит проблема была в среде.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Может быть так?

Comment: Кнопку назад я уже деактивировал. Мне нужно заблокировать доступ к строке состояния, откуда можно попасть в настройки.

Comment: Может каждый раз при попытке открытия статуса бара обрабатывать и запускать фулл скрин?

Comment: покажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html посмотри здесь, возможно подойдет что

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению некогда читать все ваши комментарии, но из того что прочел решил что у вас осталась проблема только лишь в том, чтобы заблокировать выпадающую панель. Попробуйте добавить строку:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Ну а дальше читайте [официальную документацию](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: Никогда эти доки не понимал, тупл обьяснение констант, методов, интерфейсов и прочего, большой кучей, даже читать не хочется, запомнить вообще никак. Только хардкор + SO

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы заблокировать открытие статусбара (подобно мастеру настройки (SetupWizard)) вам необходимо с помощью рефлексии вызвать метод `disable` в классе `android.os.StatusBarManager`. Если нужна поддержка всех андроидов то придется полазить по исходникам, так как могут быть разные версии метода. Вроде как, говорят, что это будет генерировать `SecurityException` с требованием выставить разрешения на статусбар в манифесте. И это конечно же ничего не изменит, в логах при установке будет написано, что данное разрешение доступно только для системных приложений.

Если есть рут права - это ничего не меняет. Впринципе, можно переносить приложение в system/app но помимо этого приложение должно быть подписано системным сертификатом, который почти никак не узнать. Но есть один выход: прошить устройства на CyanogenMod (Lineage) - там сис.ключ открытый, но я не нашел никакой информации на эту тему.

**Как вариант**
Можно поставить на устройства Xposed Framework + модуль BusyBox, 100% в нем есть функция блокировки статусбара (или вообще, скрытия) или какой-то другой модуль, или напишите свой, Xposed Framework есть на гитхабе.

**Еще?**
Возможно, дурно, но все же. При запуске приложения переименовать system/app/SystemUI.apk (или переместить (или поменять пермишны)) и обновлять граф.интерфейс, а при закрытии (+ включении устройства (вдруг сядет)) восстанавливать..

**+**
Не знаю, можно ли. Сделайте фуллскрин-приложение и в `onTouchEvent` в случае если `action = MOVE` (юзер смещает палец) закрывайте статусбар (метод `collapsePanels` (вроде) - это можно сделать без каких-либо ограничений.

P.S Во всяком случае в UС Browser при просмотре видео если открыть статусбар то видео ставится на паузу, значит можно ставить слушатель на выдвигание (там фуллскрин, свайп для показа полосы шторки останавливает видео).

**++**
Можете вместо использования рефлексии поюзать шелл (закрыть статусбар)

```
input swipe 0 100 0 0
```

Тоесть делаем свайп по Y от 100 сверху к нулю. Можно наверное это делать в каком то цикле (?)

Идеи кончились